# Separate GWT UIBinder files

Tags: gwt, uibinder

When GWT UIBinder being used by default, a pair of java source and UI template files are created under the same directory.

What are required to keep them under separate directories. e.g client/MyApp.java and client/ui/xml/MyApp.ui.xml?

**@EDIT**

Below is based on`@jonasr`'s answer, but the annotaion should be valued with rather the `file path` of the UI template than the package prefix.

```
@UiTemplate("ui/xml/MyApp.ui.xml")
interface MyAppUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyApp>
{}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using @UiTemplate annotation with full path for your ui.xml file on your interface declaration

```
@UiTemplate("com.company.ui.xml.MyApp.ui.xml")
interface MyAppUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyApp>
{}
```

Comment: Thanks. Following your answer i searched the javadoc, which has also documented this feature on `UIBinder` interface.